# VS2019 copy and paste changes tabs to spaces

Tags: formatting, editor, visual-studio-2019

I've just upgraded from VS2012 to VS2019. I have the tabs set up in Options|TextEditor|C#|Tabs as Smart, Tab Size 4, Indent Size 4, Keep Tabs (as OOTB). I have the same set in All Languages, except that it refuses to set Smart Indenting (which may or may not be relevant to the problem).

The problem is that if I copy and paste the following line in a .CS file:

```
        private bool myPrivateField1;           // Private fields should be PascalCase
```

the indenting is fine, but the tabs between the code and the comment get replaced by spaces in both the copied line and the pasted line. 2012 doesn't do this and it's really annoying.

Comment: It's worse than I thought - I did a Format Document and now all the tabs (except for the indents) have been replaced with spaces. Am I missing something??

Comment: You're not missing anything. This has been a bug from day one. Good luck submitting it through Visual Studio Feedback.

Answer (score 0):

try to deactive adaptive formatting. Tools->Options->Text Editor->Advanced than uncheck [Use Adaptive Formatting]